# must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=19f9d7d4cc76b670'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, structuremap

In my solution I have 5 projects and I need to use strucuremap. Here is my code :

```
private static readonly Lazy<Container> _containerBuilder =
            new Lazy<Container>(defaultContainer, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
        public static IContainer Container
        {
            get { return _containerBuilder.Value; }
        }
        private static Container defaultContainer()
        {
            var container = new Container(ioc =>
            {
                // map same interface to different concrete classes
                ioc.For<IUser>().Use<EFUserService>();
                ioc.For<IUnitOfWork>().Use(() => new ApplicationDBContext())();
            });
            container.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            return container;
        }
```

In this line:

```
ioc.For<IUnitOfWork>().Use(() => new ApplicationDBContext())();
```

I get this error :

> 'DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=19f9d7d4cc76b670'

I add all project in this project (this main project), update EF (6.1.3) in all project, and I use strucuremap 4.5.1.

Whats the problem? Why show me this error? How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you copy your web/app.config and packages.config to your question?

Answer (score 0):

In the project you are using Entity Framework from, you need to right click on `References`, then click `Add Reference`. From here, you can import the assembly for Entity Framework to make it available to your project.

Comment: ti's add in my project